# Data structure for selection of K elements and taking sum

Tags: algorithms, data-structures

**The problem:**

We are given an array $A$, an integer $Z$ and a value $Q$. The goal is to maximize the sum of $A$, by performing following operation any number of times:
We can select exactly $Z$ elements from the given array and perform XOR on each of them with $Q$.

Is there any data structure I can use which can perform this efficiently or any algorithm I am not aware of?

I tried finding each element's maximum possible value (using XOR/ignoring it), sorting the array and then making the selection but it did not work, which leads me to believe that the greedy approach won't work here.

I am primarily looking for an algorithm that can help or a data structure, not necessarily the code.

For example, given the array $[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], Z = 2$ and $Q = 4$, the answer is 23 as I can take XOR of 1 and 2 with 4 and of 3 and 4 with 4 as well.

Edit: The sum 23 is obtained as follows: We need to select Z (2) values at a time. So we select 1 and 2 and obtain their XOR with Q(4), which makes it 5 and 6. We then select 3 and 4 and obtain their XOR with Q, which makes them 7 and 0. Thus the final array becomes $[5,6,7,0,5] which is equal to 23 and is maximum possible sum.

Comment: Can you please add detail to either the description of how to compute the sum of $A$ or spell out how to arrive at `23`?

Comment: Sure. I'll do that.

Comment: Should get interesting for $Z \in 2 \mathbb N +1$.

Answer (score 1):

First, note that for any $a$, since XOR is associative:

$$(a \oplus b) \oplus b = a \oplus (b \oplus b)$$

Since $b \oplus b$ is $0$ and $0$ is neutral for XOR, we get that:

$$(a \oplus b) \oplus b = a \oplus (b \oplus b) = a \oplus 0 = a$$

In other words, there is no point performing XOR operation more than twice, for any $a$ with any $Q$. You can either XOR once, or not XOR at all (XOR twice)

---

Now, suppose you have an array $A$. Prepare the array $B$ as an array of the difference between $A$ before and after we XOR it:

$B_i = \max\{0, A_i \oplus Q - A_i\} $ (Since performing XOR on $A_i$ twice yields $A_i$, we can also choose $A_i$ itself).

Preparing $B$ takes $O(n)$.

Increasing the sum of $A$ is now equivalent to selecting the $Z$ XORS that their sum - difference is greatest, which is equivalent to selecting $Z$ max elements from $B$.

For that, there's a better solution than sorting ($O(n\log n)$):

- Select the $Z-th$ largest element of $B$ using selection algorithm
- Sweep $B$ and save any element that is larger than the $Z-th$ largest element

The indices of the elments chosen in $B$ determine both the elements of $A$ you select, and the XOR performed (or not performed). In total, it took $O(n)$ time.

Comment: Could you explain your algorithm on the example I have specified? Its somewhat unclear.

Comment: Which part of the algorithm is unclear to you?

Comment: The last part. Post making array B, I am supposed to select Z  max elements from it right? And then do what with them?

Comment: That selection defines the elements from $A$ that you would select, and whether or not you XOR them. Suppose from $B$ you chose $[2,4,5]$, then elements $A_2$, $A_4$, $A_5$ are selected from $A$. Whether or not to XOR them you find easily in $O(1)$ by asking whether $B_i = 0$.

Comment: Also, as per my understanding of this algorithm, it fails for [10, 15, 20, 13, 2, 1, 44] when Z = 4 and Q = 14.

Comment: so basically I check B and if Bi = 0, I select Ai but if isn't, I choose XOR of Ai with Q. Right?

Comment: Only for Z greatest elements of B, not for every elment of B

Comment: what about the other test case? [10, 15, 20, 13, 2, 1, 44], Z = 4 and Q = 14. It fails here.

Comment: "it fails here". What is the output sum, and what is a higher sum?

Comment: The output is 135 but it should be 129.

Comment: 135 is greater than 129... I don't understand the problem. You meant the other way around?

Comment: Since we have to select 4 elements at a time, 129 will be maximum achievable value. Because we'll change value at index 0,2,4,5 of the given array.

Comment: Since the algorithm obviously does not change more than $Z$ elements, it sounds like the solution suggested in your exercise is not optimal. I would also suggest debugging your implementation (if you did implement it): if you check which elements are XOR'd you can check for yourself whether the solution is feasible.

Comment: It does not change more than Z elements *in one go*. The operation can be performed multiple times.

Comment: I don't know how else to say this - sorry you don't understand. Can't explain it better than the answer. What is left is to suggest for you to review the answer again, thoroughly (judging by your last comment, you didn't understand a basic quality of XOR).